# How to split controllers by route in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a bunch of controllers and would like to segment them via route into two groups:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "r1",
                "api/v1.0/route1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               "r2",
               "api/v1.0/route2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

I thought I could do this with something like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1.0/route1")]
    public class MyController : ApiController
```

To make it go down ONLY route1, however I'm able to hit it via route2 also.

I also tried

```
[RoutePrefix("route1")]
        public class MyController : ApiController
```

With the same result.  How can I make MyController only go down route1?  Any help is greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Remove the MapHttpRoute() function calls and switch everything to attribute routing would be a simple solution.

Comment: readup on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1.0)]
public class MyController : ApiController
```

and then on the method itself

```
[Route("route1")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RouteOne(object params)
{
 ...
}


[Route("route2")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RouteTwo(object params)
{
 ...
}
```

Agree with commenter who said to leave `MapHttpRoute` alone.  Should look like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: *complains about having to touch every controller* Looks like there isn't a better way to do it, and that is mostly what I was wondering, thanks!